# How come factor vectors are less efficient than integer or even character vectors?

Tags: r

I just noticed the following:

```
set.seed(42)
vec <- sample(c("a", "b", "c"), 1e4, replace=T)
vec_fac <- factor(vec)
vec_int <- as.integer(factor(vec))

library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(vec=="b", vec_fac=="b", vec_int==2, vec_fac==2)
```

This gives to my great surprise:

```
Unit: microseconds
           expr      min        lq      mean   median       uq       max neval
     vec == "b" 2397.150 2406.5925 2499.5715 2470.637 2532.628  2881.588   100
 vec_fac == "b" 5706.932 5765.4340 6137.5441 6032.696 6401.567  8889.446   100
   vec_int == 2  510.714  541.0935  623.8341  580.506  743.695   845.305   100
   vec_fac == 2 5703.237 5772.6185 6339.6577 5975.015 6378.577 31502.869   100
```

I would have thought that factors were much more efficient than a simple character vector but it is not the case. (Of course, `vec_fac` and `vec_int` take half less memory than `vec`.)

Why are factors not as efficient as integer vectors?

Answer (score 4):

The testing requires some conversion. Have a look at the profiling below. Note that `(levels(vec_fac) == "b")[vec_fac]` is faster.

```
set.seed(42)
vec <- sample(c("a", "b", "c"), 1e4, replace=T)
vec_fac <- factor(vec)
vec_int <- as.integer(factor(vec))

library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(
  (levels(vec_fac) == "b")[vec_fac],
  vec_int == 2, 
  vec == "b", 
  vec_fac == 2,
  vec_fac == "b"
)
Unit: microseconds
                              expr     min       lq      mean   median      uq     max neval   cld
 (levels(vec_fac) == "b")[vec_fac]  62.861  69.7030  74.20981  71.8410  73.552 131.280   100 a    
                      vec_int == 2  73.124  85.0970  89.96756  86.8070  87.877 125.721   100  b   
                      vec == "b" 129.569 133.8450 138.57510 134.7005 135.129 170.621   100   c  
                      vec_fac == 2 303.611 331.8340 348.90436 334.6135 337.820 482.783   100    d 
                  vec_fac == "b" 347.656 376.7335 393.01326 379.2990 381.224 577.715   100     e
```

Profiling:

```
set.seed(42)
vec <- sample(c("a", "b", "c"), 1e8, replace=T)
vec_fac <- factor(vec)
vec_int <- as.integer(vec_fac)

Rprof()
junk <- vec_int == 2
Rprof(NULL)
summaryRprof()

Rprof()
junk <- vec == "b"
Rprof(NULL)
summaryRprof()

Rprof()
junk <- vec_fac == "b"
Rprof(NULL)
summaryRprof()

Rprof()
junk <- vec_fac == 2
Rprof(NULL)
summaryRprof()
```

Comment: I'm not sure how to interpret the output of the profiling, could you please elaborate on what you see?

Comment: The vector based comparisons only require the `==` function. The factor based comparison require additional functions like `Ops.factor`. Hence they are likely to require more time.